# Keeping value after reference cell has been changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need cell B3 to reference B1 while blank.
Once you put something in B1 it'll keep that value forever, even once B1 get's changed to something else.

This is my situation:
Basically I have a sheet that is fed by a Google form and each submission needs three key reference numbers each kept in columns a,b,c

- A = Unit Number/Individuals name (There may be duplicates down the sheet as this is per submission)
- B = Work Order (Imputed by me after actual work on unit has been done)
- C = Cry Number/Reference number (Automatically generated per submission; no duplicates)

I then have a frozen row at the top which contains a search bar that you can search for the cry number (A1)(Which has a Data Validation set to column C so that you can only search valid cry numbers) and then a cell to add a W/O to that Cry Number (B1)

In column B3:1000, I have this formula copied down:

```
B3=if(isblank($C3),"",if($A$1=$C3, SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"",$B$1),""))
```

...which makes it so that if you select say "CN-168" (A valid cry number) and in 'B1' type "W1134" that work order number will be assigned.

Now I need that work order to stay there regardless of when 'A1' changes so that you can do the process over again on another submission.

Is it possible to do with formulas? If not, then a Google Script?

[Here](http://goo.gl/gU6K4E) is a template of what I'm dealing with but not to the same scale as my Data Base

[image: screenshot]

Comment: My companies firewall seems to block your template but I suggest you do this calling the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event and intercepting `Target.Address="$B$1"`. When a change to this cell is detected, then you can do a  `.find` based on the value in cell A1 and set the value for the corresponding offset column to B1's value. Hope this guides you on your way. Cheers.

Comment: @nbayly this isnt excel

Comment: Thanks @Zig Mandel for your commentary but if you note the edit logs you'll see that this questions was tagged initially as relating to excel. Also your language and tone aren't really very in line with providing positive feedback. As an experienced member of SOF I would encourage you to foster participation with a more conciliatory note when  commenting on others peoples offerings. Cheers.

Comment: @nbayly not sure what you mean at all. I simply noted that it wasnt excel. Why that isnt positive? I even answered the question yesterday. thats not positive I guess?

Comment: @zig mandel I'm not sure what part you don't understand. The original poster had tagged his question with an excel tag which was later edited and removed after my comment. But you're right, my response was very defensive and negative so I apologize. Lastly, es un gusto que los peruanos representemos en SOF... sigue dandole ;)

Comment: Yes my point is I still cant see how my comment can be seen as offensive or rude, and not about the excel tag.

Comment: It wasn't, which is why I apologized. I was being defensive as I felt my answer was appropriate for the original question and felt I was being wronged. But in retrospect, my knee jerk reaction was not the best conduit to helping Colton, which was/is both our ultimate goals. Hope we can bury this now. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with formulas but easily done with apps script. look at the onEdit trigger and the documentation for SpreadsheetApp to setValues to the appropiate ranges.

If you want to be 100% complete you also need a time trigger (say every 10 minutes) to check that a row wasnt missed. It can be missed during apps script errors/outages or when the sheet is changed from outside the sheets webpage/app (For example using the http spreadsheet api)